# How should I wire this sauna heater?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have to change our sauna heater. The current heater has wires connected to Earth, N and L3.

I'm confused by the manual of the new heater as there is only 1 X N wire but the manual seems to suggest that there should be 2 (unless I've misread it).

The shop said that the wiring would be the same.

The new heater model is numbered 1 - 7 so it's the top diagram that seems relevant.

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zLmE.jpg)

Old:

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp2PF.jpg)

Comment: There are quite some energies involved here, are you sure that -- if at least only for insurance reasons -- you want to do this yourself when unsure?

Answer (score 2):

The diagram gives you three possible wiring options depending on your power system. The top one is for 415V three-phase (star), the middle for 240V three-phase (delta), and the bottom one for 240V single phase.

In a normal house the bottom one is what you want. Basically connect all the N terminals together, and all the L terminals together and those are your N and L points.

Note: the lower two diagrams are the same physical connectors as the top one - they just omitted drawing in the connection 7 that not used for the lower two diagrams.

Comment: It's the top diagram. I have one N wire from the existing heater but this diagram for the new heater seems to suggest that I need 2 connected to 2 + 3?

Comment: No, it's the bottom one. They are all the same, just without using pin 7.

Comment: The current heater has one wire connected to GRND, one wire connected to N and one wire connected to L3.

Comment: Obviously a different heater hence the confusion, or I would just copy that.

Comment: The heater consists of 3 individual heating elements. You wire them differently for different types of power. Unless you are in an industrial environment (such as a leisure centre) you will be single phase 240V. Ergo you wire the three heating elements in parallel as shown in the section labelled 240V single phase.

Comment: That gives you then one neutral, one live, and one ground. You then *separately* tie the two neutral connections together, and *all three* live connections together. Depending on how it is physically this may be done with a *[bus bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busbar)*.

Comment: I see that now. Time to call an electrician.

Comment: Now that you have added a picture you can plainly see the bus bar (copper strip) joining L1, L2 and L3.